How can I get the master data for the resource code & activity code in Oracle EBS R12 Batch Ticket?
To do the data analysis, I need to get the master data of the batch ticket Resource code & Activity Code in Oracle EBS R12.
This is the front-end form screenshot of the Oracle EBS batch ticket.

I have tried to find the table name in the Help -> Diagnostics -> Examine, but the database pops up the error - no table or view is available.
I want to know, what's the table name in Oracle EBS R12 back-end database stores the Resource & Activity code master data?
